# Parent Child Search at same table LINQ C#

Tags: c#, database, linq, entity-framework-core

I have a query to search in single table where records are at Parent, Child Relationship like below

| Table |
| --- |
| Id |
| ParentId |
| Name |
| Status |

so my query is like

```
var projects = from p in _projectSetupRepository.Table
                           from all in _projectSetupRepository.Table
                           where p.Status == status && p.ParentId == null &&
                                 all.Status == status && ((all.ParentId == null && all.Id == p.Id) || all.ParentId == p.Id)
                           select p;

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
                projects = projects.Where(c => c.Name.Contains(search)).OrderBy(c => c.Name);
```

but I don't get actual results of parents if search with the child's name. What was the issue in the query?

PS

> table contains thousands of data and performance is very important

PS

```
public class ProjectSetup 
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int? ParentId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool Status { get; set; }
        public ProjectSetup Project{ get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ProjectSetup> SubProjects { get; set; }
   
    }
```

| Id | ParentId | Name | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | P1 | true |
| 2 | 1 | T1 | true |
| 3 | 1 | T2 | true |
| 4 | 3 | Q1 | true |

Comment: Your query has not been well explained. if all children have parents. If a parent is a child of another parent? how are parents detected how children? what's the final result?

Comment: @AFarmanbar when record with `ParentId = null` it's parent record sorry for the confution

Comment: Are you not specifying in that query that ParentId is null? So based on my understanding it will never return a child?

Comment: `(all.ParentId == null && all.Id == p.Id)` - why are you checking if it is the same record as `p`? Don't you just want to check children? It seems like your query just returns all the parent records the really hard way? You could just leave everything about `all` (very bad naming) out of the query?

Comment: @NetMage  it's returning all child not parents. how can i write this in right way

Comment: What do you want in the answer? All parents with children with matching names? All parents and children with matching names? All parents with matching names and all parents with children with matching names? All parents with matching names and all parents with children with matching names and all children with matching names?

Comment: @NetMage you are asking the same thing? All Parents and Children withing matching name

Comment: How deep your hierarchy?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv  It goes at least 10 levels in real-world scenarios. but cannot define exactly.

Comment: Show class `Table`, i have to check your navigation properties. And what is the point to return children and parents in one flatten list?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I have added class

Comment: Bad that you donє‘t have `Parent` navigation property.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Actually Parent to a child is One to Many. Not Many to many. sorry i forgot to add that

Comment: @Gayan you are combining two questions into one, `1.` joining multi level records `2.` filtering records, Maybe a fiddle can help, try to modify the fiddle posted in the answer

Comment: No, each question is very different. All parents and children with matching name is easy: `from p in _projectSetupRepository.Table where p.Name == desiredName select p;` but I don't think that is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can find all parents with specific child name(`this query searches Level1 childs only`):

```
var status = true;
var search = "T";
var projects = (from parent in context.Projects
                join child in context.Projects on parent.Id equals child.ParentId into joinedT
                from pd in joinedT.DefaultIfEmpty()
                where parent.Status == status 
                && parent.ParentId == null //filter top level parents only?
                && pd.Name.Contains(search)
                select parent).Distinct().OrderBy(c => c.Name);
foreach(var p in projects)
{
    Console.WriteLine(p.Id+":"+p.Name);
}

Console.WriteLine("Found results:"+ projects.Count());
```

here's fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/PaCidA

If you are looking for multi-level solution I suggest you to take a look at `hierarchyid` data type and its usage in EF LINQ 
https://softwarehut.com/blog/tech/hierarchyid-entity-framework
https://kariera.future-processing.pl/blog/hierarchy-in-the-entity-framework-6-with-the-hierarchyid-type/

Answer (score 1):

Check for performance the folloging algorithm. Idea that we can Include several `Project` and check on the client what to load again. Algorithm uses EF Core navigation properties fixup.

```cs
var query = in_projectSetupRepository.Table
    .Include(p => p.Project.Project.Project) // you can increase count  of loaded parents
    .Where(p => p.Status == status)
    .AsQueryable();

var loadedDictionary = new Dictionary<int, ProjectSetup>>();

var projects = query;

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
    projects = projects.Where(c => c.Name.Contains(search));

while (true)
{
    var loaded = projects.ToList();

    // collect loaded with parents
    foreach(var p in loaded)
    {
        var current = p;
        do 
        {
            if (!loadedDictionary.ContainsKey(current.Id))
                loadedDictionary.Add(current.Id, current);

            current = current.Project;
        }
        while (current != null)
    }

    // collect Ids of incomplete
    var idsToLoad = loadedDictionary.Values
        .Where(x => x.ParentId != null && x.Project == null)
        .Select(x => x.ParentId.Value)
        .ToList();

    //  everything is ok
    if (idsToLoad.Count == 0)
        break;

    // make query to load another portion of objects
    projects = query.Where(p => idsToLoad.Contains(p.Id));
}

var result = loadedDictionary.Values
    .OrderBy(c => c.Name)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I tried this unfortunatly code is not compiling

Comment: Yes, because it is written in text editor. Which part?

Comment: loadedDictionary cannot be check Contains extension with Id

Comment: Fixed, it should be Containskey